# C embedded systems stack and heap size

Tags: c, embedded, heap-memory, system, stack-size

How could I determine the current stack and heap size of a running C program on an embedded system? Also, how could I discover the maximum stack and heap sizes that my embedded system will allow? I thought about linearly calling malloc() with an increasing size until it fails to find the heap size, however I am more interested in the size of the stack.

I am using an mbed NXP LPC1768, and I am using an offline compiler developed on GitHub called gcc4mbed.

Any better ideas? All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this will all depend on the hardware, C library, and compiler toolchain, so, as told, read the hardware specs.

Comment: What about programatically finding this information out?

Comment: What is your hardware and software system?? How do you compile?

Comment: I am using an mbed NXP LPC1768, and I am using an offline compiler developed on GitHub called gcc4mbed.

Comment: "an offline compiler"? isn't that just "a compiler"?

Comment: The standard compiler used for the mbed I have is an online compiler. Thus I wanted to be clearly specific as to what I am using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this look at your linker script, this will define how much space you have allocated to each.

For stack size usage do this:

At startup (before C main()) during initialization of memory, init all your stack bytes to known values such as 0xAA, or 0xCD.  Run your program, at any point you can stop and see how many magic values you have left.  If you don't see any magic values then you have overflowed your stack and weirdness may start to happen.

At runtime you can also check the last 4 bytes or so (maybe last two words, this is really up to you).  If they don't match your magic value then force a reset.  This only works if your system is well behaved on reset and it is best if it starts up quick and isn't doing something "real time" or mission critical.

Here's a [really helpful whitepaper from IAR](http://www.iar.com/Global/Resources/Developers_Toolbox/Building_and_debugging/Mastering_stack_and_heap_for_system_reliability.pdf) on the subject.

Comment: NP; I too think that the Google redirect URLs are unsightly.

Answer (score 8):

A crude way of measuring at runtime the current stack size is to declare

```
 static void* mainsp;
```

then start your `main`  with e.g:

```
 int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    int here;
    mainsp = (void*) &here;
```

then inside some leaf routine, when the call stack is deep enough, do something similar to

```
    int local;
    printf ("stack size = %ld\n", 
            (long) ((intptr_t) &local - (intptr_t) mainsp));
```

Statically estimating from full source code of an application the required stack size is in general undecidable (think of recursion, function pointers), and in practice very difficult (even on a severely restricted class of applications). Look into [Couverture](http://libre.adacore.com/tools/coverage/). You might also consider customizing a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with your [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (perhaps [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) in mid 2021; email me to `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr` about it) for such purposes, but that won't be easy and will give you over-approximations.

If compiling with GCC, you might use the [return address bultins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) to query the stack frame pointer at run time. On some architectures it is not available with some optimization flags. You could also use the `-Wstack-usage=`*byte-size* and/or `-Wframe-larger-than=`*byte-size* [warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) to recent GCC.

As to how heap and stack spaces are distributed, this is system dependent. You might parse `/proc/self/maps` file on Linux. See [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). You could limit stack space on Linux in user-space using [setrlimit(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html).

Be however aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

With multi-threaded applications things could be more difficult. Read some [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Notice that in *simple* cases, GCC may be capable of [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimizations. You could compile your `foo.c` with `gcc -Os -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` and look inside the generated `foo.s` assembler code.

If you don't care about portability, consider also using the [extended `asm` features](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) of GCC.

Comment: I suppose your `&sp` is actually `&here`.

Comment: You're using the fact that a function-scope variable is declared on the stack, so its address is the current stack pointer, but you can also do this with [GCC's explicit register variables extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html) and write `char *stack_ptr asm ("sp");` to get an alias to the current stack pointer.  On an ARM Cortex-M3 like the mbed, 'sp' is the name of the stack pointer, but you'd need to change this for other architectures.  This would be especially useful if you've got lots of local variables.

Comment: You also assume that there is a unified stack for data and function return addresses.  I've worked on one nasty uP many years ago where this was not the case!